# How can I get this basic android service example app to work?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service

I am new to android app development and I am learning android services. So I created this basic app that demonstrates a service and I just cannot understand what is wrong. The logcat shows it cannot find the MyService class file. The app stops when i click the start button. Here is my program.

MainActivity.java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button start,stop;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        start = findViewById(R.id.start);
        stop = findViewById(R.id.stop);

        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class));
            }
        });

        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

MyService.java

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class MyService extends Service {
    private MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, Settings.System.DEFAULT_ALARM_ALERT_URI);
        player.setLooping(true);
        player.start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        player.stop();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.service_test">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Service_Test">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".MyService"></service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is the logcat:
[image]

Comment: Why you start a service by calling `startActivity()`. Use `startService()` instead and take a  look around other answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should register your service in the manifest:

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.my.packagename.MyService" />
```

and start the service via:

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

Comment: I've already done that. You can check the manifest file.

Comment: you are starting a Service like an activity. startService not startActivity

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class));
```

by:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
    startForegroundService( new Intent(this, MyService.class));
} else {
    startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
}
```

Also add to Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
```

Foreground services continue in the background when the screen is off.

Comment: You can use ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, intent). It already handles when to call startService and when to call startForegroundService.